# How can I run any JS function after config the username and password to allow user access my Parse Server?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

Firstly, sorry for my bad English. I'm working with Parse server, in order to allow my teammate access my local server, I config the server like this

```
{
    "apps": [
      {
        "serverURL": "http://10.30.176.147:1337/parse",
        "appId": "MyFirstApp",
        "masterKey": "myMasterKey",
        "appName": "MyApplication"
      }
    ],
    "users": 
    [
      {
          "user":"admin",
          "pass":"pass"
      }
    ]
}
```

But after that, I can not executive any method. Example:

```
Parse.serverURL = 'http://10.30.176.147:1337/parse';

var user = new Parse.User();

user.set("username", "alex@gmail.com.vn");
user.set("password", "123456");
user.set("email", "alex@gmail.com.vn");
user.set("foo", "bar");
user.set("name", "Alex Ho");
user.set("gender", "female");

user.signUp().then(function success(){
  console.log("Signed up", user);
}, function error(err){
  console.error(err);
});
```

It returns an error message like this:

**[object Object] {
code: 100,
message: "XMLHttpRequest failed: "Unable to connect to the Parse API""
}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you missed to initialize the SDK:

```js
Parse.initialize("MyFirstApp", null, "myMasterKey");
```